# Normalizing data in a factorial ANOVA

Tags: anova

Suppose you have a 2 x 2 between-subjects ANOVA, so there are four groups.  You see that the data are negatively skewed in all four cells. You can’t count on the Central Limit Theorem to provide immunity because your sample sizes are small. The textbooks recommend a data transform, perhaps a square root transform:

```
           TransformedScore = SQRT(k – RawScore), where k = the largest RawScore + 1
```

Here’s my question. Is this transform performed separately within each of the four cells, thus using different values of k in each of the four cells? That would normalize the distributions within each of the cells, but it also means that the highest raw score in each cell ends up with the same transformed value of 1, even though those highest raw scores in each cell might be very different raw score values. It doesn’t seem right that different raw scores should end up having the same value following the transformation.

So, if one doesn’t transform the data separately in each cell, how is it done? Does one do a single transform on the entire data set? That would normalize the entire data set, but it doesn’t seem that it would be very effective in normalizing the distributions in each of the cells.

How exactly does one transform the data in a factorial ANOVA so as to normalize the distributions in each cell?

Comment: I would have thought doing it over the whole data-set would be best. Can you clarify why you are reluctant to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can't normalize differently in each cell, for the reason you posit. The results would be uninterpretable. You can transform the whole data set, and that probably will substantially reduce the skew in each cell (since all are skewed in the same direction) although it might not make them normal.

Why transform at all?  Why not use some other method than ANOVA?  For instance you could use quantile regression or robust regression, neither of which assume that the errors are normally distributed.